Adding another instance to JFrog Artifactory HA
I'm looking for a correct way of adding another Artifactory instance to JFrog Artifactory HA with some modifications.
Currently I am having 3 nodes. I would like to add another one.
I have 3 licenses so my idea is to shutdown one of the existing instances, install a new Artifactory instance simply by following HA installation guide and start it.
I should be able to shutdown recently started instance and restart the original one.
I am looking for some document like 'replacing an JFrog Artifactory instance with another instance', but I was not able to find it or make sure that this would be the correct way.

Yes your idea is completely fine.
When you shut down one node, the license that was attached is freed.
You can then start a new node and the license will attach to that node dynamically.

Just a follow up question, should I put this new Artifactory instance behind the same Load Balancer before I start? When I simply try to start a new instance (without adding it behind the same Load Balancer as existing Artifactory instances) , It fails to start. I was thinking this can be tested without Load Balancer manipulation in the first place, just to see if this instance can be joined to the cluster or not. I can share the errors occurred while trying to start new instance, if needed.

You do not need to put it behind the load balancer for it to start correctly. Your thinking is again correct. You can share the errors here or open a support ticket with Jfrog, as this isn't exactly the correct forum for back and forth responses.
The main log to look at is the artifactory-service.log, the other logs can introduce a lot of noise about failures to reach 8046 if artifactory micor service fails to start.
